# "Any" vs. "anything" — are these answers the same?

Tags: grammaticality, differences

Could you please tell me if these sentences are correct and the same?

> How much luggage do you have?
>
> 1. I don't have any.
> 2. I don't have any luggage.
> 3. I don't have anything.

Comment: This question is deemed _General reference_ or belongs at http://ell.stackexchange.com/
1 and 2 are the same, 3 means no luggage nor anything else (cabin/hand luggage/money)

Answer (score 2):

In answer to that specific question, all three are grammatical, but #1 is the most natural, #2 is slightly unnatural because it is needlessly long (short answers are preferred), and #3 is definitely the most unnatural and should be avoided.  *Anything* is too general a word to use in response to such a specific question.  Another natural answer would be *none:* brief and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the question, as in the question:

> How much luggage do you have?

A common noun is used, *luggage*, which is simply referring to something that we can count. So *any* and *anything* are both correct for it.